# AVPlayerViewController not supporting PiP on iPhone

Tags: ios, avplayerviewcontroller, avkit

I have followed Apple's [steps](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/adopting_picture_in_picture_in_a_standard_player) in order to get my `AVPlayerViewController` to support in-app and background Picture in Picture playback.

```
func playerViewController(_ playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController, restoreUserInterfaceForPictureInPictureStopWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
        completionHandler(false)
    }
}
```

The button shows on iPad, but not on iPhone, and video playback does not continue when going to the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

Further to implementing the required `AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate`, you also need to ensure you are setting the right audio session category, like so:

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
    try audioSession.setCategory(.playback)
} catch {
    print("Setting category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback failed.")
}
```